# how to give WCF application access to a network share folder?

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7.5

I developed a WCF application, it will pick up a file from a network share folder and move it to another place.

I kept getting this error message:

```
" The account used is a computer account. Use your global user account or local user account to access this server."
```

the Identity of the WCF application pool is "ApplicationPoolIdentity". I believe wcf application uses this account to access files on network.

I want to know if I can give this account access to the network folder. if not, what should I do to create a global user account to access the network folder?

Comment: `ApplicationPoolIdentity` will not have access to your network share (that's a good thing).  Is this a corporate environment that you're working in?

Comment: yes. this is a corporate env. i did some research at work, seems like using impersonation in web.config might be a solution.

Comment: In your WCF app you can write some code to impersonate a domain user (one that has access to your network share).  This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net